# Javascript loop within HTML code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have the following lines (I'm taking a variable from the server, `NodeJS` using `EJS` for templating):

```
<% for(var i=0; i < gens.length; i++) { %>
    <option value=<%= gens[i].gene %>><%= gens[i].gene %></option>
<% } %>
```

I'd like to substitute `gens` for another array from my Javascript code. How could I do it? It is giving me an error `Variable not defined`.

EDIT: Here is where I define the variable:

```
<script>
    var functionlist = '<%= gens %>';
    functionlist = functionlist.split(",");
</script>
```

Comment: That's most probably ASP.NET's ASPX technology.

Comment: @Luaan you are totally wrong. My question is about JavaScript code happening both at the server and client side.

Comment: Well, it's nice of you to come a year later to add that information to your question, but it most likely isn't going to help now. If you're still looking for a solution, you might want to consider deleting this question and asking it again - while giving all the relevant information in the first place :) If you no longer care about the Q/A, just delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You understand that you are using ASP.NET which is a server-side language and you want to use Javascript which is a client side language? If yes then:

Let's say you have a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) array in your javascript like the one below:

```
var gens = ['gen-1', 'gen-2', 'gen-3'];
```

then you could loop through that and create your select options using a tiny bit of [JQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
for(var index in gens)
{
  $('<option value="'+gens[index]+'">'+gen[index]+'</option>').appendTo('#gens');
}
```

And your HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="gens"></select>
```

Comment: Would be nice to put a comment on why you down voted a perfectly good answer.

Comment: Did not downvote but `for(var gen in gens)` does not work the way you think. `gen` will be the indices of the array and **not** the elements. JS is not Python

Comment: Should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/4f2co1bm/

I changed "var gen" to "var index". In the for loop you can now use "gens[index]"

Comment: all wrong, my question was about JavaScript code happening at both the server side and the client side, NodeJS

Comment: What @Luaan said in his comment above.